# What is required for dist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, bower

I'm using gulp to build a distribution (dist) folder for my Angular app.

So I've gathered all the controllers/services JS files as well as my CSS, now I need to do the contents of the bower folder.

I've tried to concat all the JS files (using gulp-useref) however I keep seeing an error around a dependency missing.

I tried copying the entire bower_components folder however I keep on seeing the error:

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module theRoutes due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
```

And the HTML is:

```
<!-- build:js assets/deps.js -->
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Your code is not prepared to minification. You should use something like `ng-annotate`

Comment: Can you show us where theRoutes is mentioned in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Dependency-injections like this:

```
function($http) {
 // ...  
}
```

will be broken after minification.

You should annotate them before:

```
['$http', function($http) {
 // ...
}]
```

You can use some automation tool for this. For example [ng-annotate](https://github.com/Kagami/gulp-ng-annotate) or [ng-min](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ngmin)

Comment: Ah thanks - I'll take a look into that `ng-annotate`.